# Why compiler is not able to optimize out vtable in this case (static keyword / singleton pattern)

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, vtable, devirtualization

By using godbolt, I can verify that clang++ and gcc++ are able to optimize out vtable when single type pattern is not used with static keyword.

```
#include <iostream>

class ISquare
{
public:
    virtual int square(int num) const;

    int field;
};

class Square final : public ISquare
{
public:
    int inline square(const int num) const override final
    {
        return (num * num);
    }
};

int main(const int count, char**)
{
    // compiler is not able to optimize vtable away if static keyword in sq
    static Square sq;
    const ISquare& s = sq; 

    //const Square& s = Square(); // OK compiler is smart (eliminated vtable)
    //const ISquare& s = Square(); // OK compiler is smart (eliminated vtable)

    std::cout << s.field << '\n';

    const auto r = s.square(count);
    return r;
}
```

So if the code base relies heavily on singleton pattern where a method or free function returns a reference to instance that is not in local scope, then vtable elimination does not work as expected.

Following flags were used to compile

```
-std=c++11 -Os -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fdata-sections -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/QqJWlI)

Comment: More difficult to reason with static variables which are less scoped (in general cases).